# How to get affected rows using mysqli?

Tags: php, mysqli

After running a query using mysqli, I want to know whether it actually affected any rows. For example,

```
$res = mysqli("UPDATE table SET name='name' where id=1");
```

How to get count of affected rows?

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Remove the line:

```
$mysqli->close();
```

from the function. and this will work.

```
function mysqli($query){

$mysqli = new mysqli('test','test','test','test');
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    printf("Bad connect: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}
$result = $mysqli->query("SET NAMES utf8");
$result = $mysqli->query("set character_set_client='utf8'");
$result = $mysqli->query("set collation_connection='utf8_general_ci'");
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$arr = array($result,$mysqli);
return $arr;
}
```

Amd the use like this:

```
$res2 = mysqli("INSERT INTO Table (name, value) VALUES ('$name', '$value')");
echo $res2[1]->affected_rows;
```

And your result will be in this variable: `res2[0];`

Read this answer: [mysqli_affected_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, object given](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9456873/mysqli-affected-rows-expects-parameter-1-to-be-mysqli-object-given#9456892)

Answer (score 6):

An excerpt from my [mysqli tutorial](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli):

> The number of rows affected by the INSERT, UPDATE and DELETE query could be quite useful. What is interesting, mysqli has not one but *two* facilities that can return such a number.
> One of them is familiar `affected_rows` property:
>
> ```
> $db->query("DELETE FROM users");
> echo $db->affected_rows();
> ```
>
> But one must remember that MySQL will return here only the number of rows that were actually changed. If a row were found but the new data is the same as old, MySQL won't count such a row towards that number. Luckily, mysqli has an unique [mysqli_info()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.info.php) function which returns separate results for the the number of rows found and affected by a DML query. In any other driver, including PDO, you can have either one or another but not both at once. Although it returns a *string*, a simple code could be written to parse its result into [a neat array](https://phpize.online/?phpses=e523d3de83547eae4762888ac8f977a8).
>
> So, a bit more readable version of this code can be made into a simple function like this
>
> ```
> function mysqli_info_array($mysqli) {
>    preg_match_all('~: (\d+)~', $mysqli->info, $matches); 
>    return [
>        'matched' => (int)$matches[1][0],
>        'changed' => (int)$matches[1][1],
>        'warnings' => (int)$matches[1][2],
>    ];
> }
> ```
>
> One can easily check the number of found and affected rows separately. For example, given we are updating just a single row,
>
> ```
> $db->query("update test set i=2");
> $info = mysqli_info_array($db);
> if ($info['matched'] === 0) {
>    $result = "No rows were matched";
> } elseif($info['changed'] === 0) {
>    $result = "Rows were found but not updated";
> } else {
>    $result = "Rows were found and updated";
> }
> ```

Comment: but if i use it fucnction me not need write connetc to mysql every time. i write 1 line instead of 5

Comment: The thing is no what you write but what your code does. it should connect ONLY ONCE. There should be only ONE CONNECTION PER SCRIPT, do you understand that?

Comment: yes but i have only one connection for one script. and i caqn check connect - if connect alreay bot exitst - make connect, else - not make connect

Comment: you aren't. in this function you are connecting every time you run a query.

Answer (score 3):

Remove $mysqli->close(); And make use of

```
$mysqli->query("INSERT INTO Table (name, value) VALUES ('$name', '$value')"); 
echo $mysqli->affected_rows;
```